# What is the rest call for getting feed in linkedin api

Tags: linkedin-api

In linkedin documentation i learn something like {service} in rest api call but I'm not able to understand that. 
Can anyone please eloborate about this rest api.

Eg: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/{service}

Answer (score 0):

For Receiving linkedin Feeds you can call this url

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/activityFeeds?q=networkShares

It will only give you the posts shared by your network.

For more details go through the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/activity-feed#).